# Is it possible to return both a dictionary or series as well as a dataframe from a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a function that takes data and does calculations and appends them to a data frame. At the end, I make a dictionary that returns averages/max/mins etc from several of the columns. It'll essentially be a summary of the final data frame. I would like to have the function return both the summary as well as the data frame so i can use each in a different subsequent function.

Is this doable?

Comment: yes, 'return your_dict, your_dataframe'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you can. In python you can return a tuple from any function. Essentially you will be able to return multiple variables, even if these variables are of a different "type"
Here is an example that I think relates to your problem:

```
def example_function(a, b):
   a += 1
   b += " bar"
   c = "baz"
   return a, b, c

var1, var2, var3 = example_function(0, "foo")
```

Now you would be able to use var1, var2, and var3 however you like. You can return dictionaries, lists, tuples etc as well

Comment: ah ok got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a function that takes a DataFrame, manipulates it and returns both the new DataFrame and the summary.  You could also return a Series, take in a dictionary, etc, but the scaffolding is there.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(5), index=list('abcde'))
print(df)
   0
a  0
b  1
c  2
d  3
e  4


def transform_and_summarize(df):
        df = pd.concat([df,df+1])
        return df, df.describe()

new_df, stats = transform_and_summarize(df)

print(new_df)
   0
a  0
b  1
c  2
d  3
e  4
a  1
b  2
c  3
d  4
e  5

print(stats)
               0
count  10.000000
mean    2.500000
std     1.581139
min     0.000000
25%     1.250000
50%     2.500000
75%     3.750000
max     5.000000
```